# Rails - Update single partial on a page with multiple partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial, voting

I have a page with multiple posts. I would like each post's votes to update after the user votes and not have to reload the page. I've looked and looked, but most people who've run into this issue have only one partial on the page so they can just use the id of the partial's containing div.

I've tried using Ajax and jQuery but keep running into problems. Right now, the vote updates correctly but it's changes all the partials on one link. I've tried setting a dynamic id  for each partial but it only changes the first one because the @post variable is being set to the last post. So, even if I voted on the third post, the first post's partial will change instead of the third.

I am on rails 3.2.14 and ruby 2.0

Here's my code:

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<% all_posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="votes-box">
    <%= render partial: 'vote', locals: {post: post}  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**posts/_vote.html.erb**

```
 <%= link_to '', vote_post_path(post, type: 'up' ), remote: true, method: 'post', class: 'upvote' %>
 <div class="vote-rep"><%= post.reputation_for(:votes).to_i %> Rep</div>
 <%= link_to '', vote_post_path(post, type: 'down' ), remote: true, method: 'post', class: 'downvote' %>
```

**vote.js.erb**

```
$(".votes-box").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'vote', locals: {post: @post}).html_safe %>");
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def vote
  value = params[:type] == 'up' ? 1 : -1
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.js
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to add id to each post in html at first, and then only update the desired id in js response.

The template at first

```
<% all_posts.each do |post| %>
  <%# Or you can use `content_tag_for` %>
  <%# in following line to generate id automatically. %>
  <div id="post_#{post.id}">
    <div class="votes-box">
      <%= render partial: 'vote', locals: {post: post}  %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then in response js

```
$("#post_#{post.id} .votes-box").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'vote', 
                                          locals: {post: @post}).html_safe %>");
```

Comment: I tried that and although the vote got added, the partial didn't change. I also tried using the <%%> operators (instead of #{}) which also didn't help.

Comment: If you can update all posts in DOM previous, you shouldn't have problem at this. Please check if the server response is correct, if they are js code, paste them into browser console and try.

Comment: I figured it out. I had use "post_<%= post.id %>" in the view and "#post_<%= @post.id %>" in the js file. Thanks for the help!